# string.find with new lines

Tags: string, lua

Why `string.find` returns nil in this case?

```
local str = -- some string with several lines
local pos = string.find(str, "\r\n")
```

I'm sure the string contains new line sequence **\r\n**.

I even tried searching for **\r**, **\n** but also `\\r\\n`.

Turning off pattern matching didn't help

Edit: The string `str` is loaded from a file.

Comment: -1: not providing enough code to reproduce the issue and indicating the problem is with string.find instead of the file read.

Comment: How exactly are you reading the file in? You stated below that you're not using io.open().

Comment: Byte, by byte, because the game engine does not expose direct functions to extract files from the game data files. So, I have to it by hand.

Comment: you must show your code  how to make `str`

Answer (score 4):

> some string with several lines

If this is done using Lua's `[[]]` syntax, the resulting Lua string will not have \r\n's in them, even if you save the Lua file as Dos text. This is in accord with [Section 2.1 of the Lua Reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1).

---

So you're loading the string from a file. Lua uses C-standard io for file access. Your `io.open` will more or less call `fopen`. And `fopen` defaults to doing text translation, so it will convert \r\n to \n for you. If you don't want this, then you need to suffix `io.open`'s "mode" string with "b", as stated in [Section 5.7 of the Lua Reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.7).

Why do you even want to search for \r\n anyway? Why not just search for \n?

Comment: No, the string is actually loaded from a file.

Answer (score 3):

How sure are you?

```
$ ./lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> str="hello\r\nworld"
> pos = string.find(str, "\r\n")
> print (pos)
6
```

Comment: I'm not saying this doesn't work. However, I'm loading the string from a file.

Comment: In that case, your question should be "why does loading a file into a string change the line endings?" and show your code for that.

Comment: It doesn't - I write the string back to a temporary file, and line endings \r\n are there.

Comment: It does - unless you are opening your file in binary mode as Stuart tells you to.  See http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.2.html.  We can't be any more help without you showing the code that creates `str`.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using, and what mode are you opening the file in (the second parameter to `io.open`)? If you're opening it as text (`'r'` or `'w'` mode specifiers without `b` - if unspecified, `io.open` will use `'r'`), Windows will convert all `'\r\n'` instances when reading from a file file handle to '\n', so you would want to look for `'\n'`.

If you really need Windows to preserve `'\r\n'`, you have to include the binary specifier when you open the file to suppress this conversion:

```
local file = io.open('filename.txt','rb') --note the 'b'
```

Comment: First, I'm not using `io.open` to load the file. Second, as I said, I tried to search for `'\n'` but no go. Anyway, I used a workaround, I'm searching for the last character before `'\r\n'` - in my case it's always `\"`

Comment: Well, the code is pretty complicated. I use services of an game engine to load file from its game data archives. As I've already said - I'm sure there are `\r\n` characters, as I use `io` module to print debug log, and that log _does_ contain these characters (checked on binary level).

Comment: In that case, you'd be better off rewriting your question to ask about this specific game and provide the code you're using to load this file.

Comment: Thanks for downvote, man! As I have already said, the string _contains_ `\r\n` characters, I'm sure - it's just the find function cannot find them.